# ArrayFormula that refers to the previous row? (Circular dependency error)

Tags: excel, google-sheets, array-formulas

I'm having trouble with what seems like it would be quite a common requirement: an array formula calculation that incorporates prior rows. The issue seems to be that all cells in the array formula are evaluated at once, and so it thinks there's a circular dependency, and gives that error.

I've mocked up a [toy example on Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X06knbcduIPvwZtfrfhQhcLbkNrfz-yY4e9PFmTCg1Q/edit?usp=sharing) which you should be able to see and comment on. (I've disallowed edit access to prevent vandalism.)

It looks like this, where everything is in row `2`, and bullets 1,2,3,4 refer to columns `A`,`B`,`C`,`D` respectively:

1. 'Change' - blank for manual entry
2. 'Ex. interest' - `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(B2:B)>2, OFFSET(D2:D, -1, 0) + A2:A,))`
3. 'Interest rate' - blank for manual entry
4. 'Balance' - `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(D2:D)=2, 0, B2:B*(1+C2:C)))`

The idea is to have the interest compound (with a possibly variable rate) and the option of a plus/minus capital change on each row, however, cells `B2` and `D2` (points 2, 4) error `#REF`, and on hover report a 'circular dependency'.

I've tried everything I can think of: `OFFSET`, `INDIRECT`, `D1:D` (instead of `2`), even a helper column to do nothing but refer to the previous row of `D` (that just caused a three-column circular dependency instead).

How can I have the 'ex. interest' column refer to the 'balance' column of the previous row in an array formula without causing this error?

Similar questions solve this with `SUMIF` over the rows, conditioned on the row being less than the 'current' row in the array formula. <s>I can't see that this could work in my case, since I would need to multiply the whole running sum by the interest at each step.</s> I tried `SUMIF(... "="&DATE(...) ...)` to refer to the previous single row; this works in a helper column to print the offset balance, but trying to use it (with iterative calculation on per below) just behaves like it's zero.

At @JackBrown's suggestion, I enabled iterative calculation which rids the circular dependency error, however it still doesn't work - the second filled row gets a value of `0` from the previous row, despite the previous row having a non-zero value. As if it took the value on an early iteration, and didn't update on change.

Comment: Reason for downvote?

Comment: Have you tried this? File>Spreasheet Settings>Calculation>Iterative calculation= On. Hope that helps!

Comment: @JackBrown Actually, I spoke too soon - that resolves the circular dependency, but it seems to get `0` as the value for the balance on the previous row, i.e. before it gets its value and doesn't update.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you are trying to calculate? Could you create new columns with expected values?

Comment: @JackBrown 'Ex. interest' should be prior 'balance' + 'change'. I've added a column to show the expected value via a 'standard' formula dragged down.

Comment: Unclear to me why you removed the tag [tag:excel] @MaxMakhrov? I'd be happy with a solution that worked on either platform, even if not both.

Comment: ArrayFormulas that expands on array automatically exists only in Google Sheets. In Excel you just need to make smart table and use fomula: `=If(row()=2,A2*(1+B2),(A1+C1)*(1+B2))`

Comment: @MaxMakhrov I see, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Excel

In excel make smart table and use formula:

`=If(row()=2,A2*(1+B2),(A1+C1)*(1+B2))`

Please download sample file here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B79ClRnKS87QTTR5VDBld0plajg/view?usp=sharing[image]

---

## Google Sheets

I've made a research in order to try solving your problem.
Short answer: I can't do this and I believe that's impossible.

**Background**

I simplified the case to the task of finding future rate value with changing rates:

```
Rate+   Recursive formula for rate
1.00%   101.0000%    =(1+A2)
1.50%   102.5150%    =B2*(1+A3)
1.10%   103.6427%    =B3*(1+A4)
1.10%   104.7827%    =B4*(1+A5)
```

Then I've made an array by hand to get the same result and got this:

```
={1+A2;
  1+A2+(1+A2)*A3;
  1+A2+(1+A2)*A3+(1+A2+(1+A2)*A3)*A4;
  1+A2+(1+A2)*A3+(1+A2+(1+A2)*A3)*A4+(1+A2+(1+A2)*A3+(1+A2+(1+A2)*A3)*A4)*A5}
```

As you see, the number of arguments grows very fast:

```
1  = 2 ^1 - 1   1+B2         
3  = 2 ^2 - 1   1+B2+(1+B2)*B3 
7  = 2 ^3 - 1   1+B2+(1+B2)*B3+(1+B2+(1+B2)*B3)*B4   
15 = 2 ^4 - 1   1+B2+(1+B2)*B3+(1+B2+(1+B2)*B3)*B4 + ...
```

And to calculate the result for final row we need `2^n - 1` variables:

- for row 32 this number is 4 294 967 295!

That's why arrayformula can't handle calculations even when you enable `Iterative calculation= On`

---

**Workaroud**
But this is very simple task for recursive functions or scripts, because they can remember the last found value. So I suggest writing script and use it as custom arrayformula:

```
function futureValue(values, rates) {

  var result = [];
  var resultCurrent = 0;

  for (var i = 0, len = values.length; i < len; i++)
  {
    resultCurrent = (+values[i] + resultCurrent) * (1 + +rates[i]);
    result.push(resultCurrent);
  }

  return result;

}
```

Links:

1. [Sample file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PNfHEuR05T5txXzU4G5bux07IXnZcaXXycRxe_3IgCY/edit#gid=0) with the script working
2. [Guide on custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: Thanks for this, I did consider a script, but stopped when it wanted me to launch a separate web-app, and save the script as a different file somewhere else, and wasn't making it easy to determine how to use it, etc. I'll leave the bounty open for now in case someone pops up to refute your belief that it's impossible :) - an ArrayFormula would be ideal, but otherwise I'll go with the script or switch to Excel. Thanks :)

Comment: I've added the link to the file with the script.

Comment: This formula returns inaccurate results, see value in `C3`.